# Как посчитать процентное соотношение для каждого объекта?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

У меня есть огромный дата сет на миллион строк, в котором есть название товара (`product_id`) и номера заказов (`order_id`), в которых эти товары приобретаются. Также у меня есть столбец (`reordered`), который отвечает за то, перезаказывается ли этот товар (1) или нет (0).

Мне нужно посчитать для каждого продукта как часто он перезаказывается, т.е., как я это понимаю, поделить кол-во раз перезаказа на общее количество взаимодействий этого товара.

```
        product_id  reordered  order_id  \
0            35108          1   1773739   
1            35108          1    421943   
2            35108          1   1292727   
3            35108          1    560282   
4            35108          1   1329397   
...            ...        ...       ...   
907001       38046          0   2122080   
907002        5453          1   1059039   
907003       29000          0   2913355   
907004        4908          0   1003143   
907005       17645          0    476860   

                                             product_name  aisle_id  \
0                                           Salted Butter        36   
1                                           Salted Butter        36   
2                                           Salted Butter        36   
3                                           Salted Butter        36   
4                                           Salted Butter        36   
...                                                   ...       ...   
907001                                     Braunschweiger       106   
907002                   100% Juice, Organic, Pomegranate        98   
907003                Enchilada Sauce Spices & Seasonings       104   
907004  Smooth & Silky Head and Shoulders Smooth & Sil...        22   
907005  Fruit Refreshers Grapefruit and Oranges in Pom...         4   

        department_id  
0                  16  
1                  16  
2                  16  
3                  16  
4                  16  
...               ...  
907001             12  
907002              7  
907003             13  
907004             11  
907005              9
```

Написал следующую функцию, но работает она очень медленно:
n - количество возвратов и невозвратов, ставлю 10 обычно, чтобы не использовались товары, которые очень редки в продаже

```
def percentReorder(n):
    percent, index = [], []
    productList = new_df["product_name"].unique().tolist()
    for i in productList:
        aux_df= new_df[new_df["product_name"] == i]
        if len(aux_df) >= n:
            ones = len(aux_df[aux_df['reordered']==1])
            zeros = len(aux_df[aux_df['reordered']==0])

            percent.append(ones/(zeros+ones))
            index.append(i)
    return percent, index
```

Как можно переписать иначе, чтобы выполнялось намного быстрее?

Comment: Ну, видимо, нужно сделать `groupby` по `product_name`, взять столбец `reordered`, саггрегировать `sum` и `len`, ну и потом в получившихся данных разделить эту `sum` на `len`. Без готового примера данных код писать сложно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаточно сгруппировать фрейм по `"product_id"` и взять среднее арифметическое по столбцу `"reordered"` в каждой группе.

Пример:

```
In [274]: df
Out[274]:
   product_id  reordered
0       35108          1
1       35108          1
2       35108          1
3       35108          1
4       35108          1
5       12345          0
6       12345          0
7       12345          1

In [275]: df.groupby("product_id")["reordered"].mean()
Out[275]:
product_id
12345    0.333333
35108    1.000000
Name: reordered, dtype: float64
```

если значение нужно получить в качестве нового столбца, скопировав значение для каждой строки, тогда можно использовать `.transform()`:

```
In [278]: df["pct_reordered"] = df.groupby("product_id")["reordered"].transform("mean")

In [279]: df
Out[279]:
   product_id  reordered  pct_reordered
0       35108          1       1.000000
1       35108          1       1.000000
2       35108          1       1.000000
3       35108          1       1.000000
4       35108          1       1.000000
5       12345          0       0.333333
6       12345          0       0.333333
7       12345          1       0.333333
```

Comment: А, точно, есть же готовая `mean`, чегой то я )

Comment: Вообще я ждал традиционно `query`, surprise

Comment: @CrazyElf, зато у вас более универсальное решение - `.mean()` будет работать только для единиц и нулей) PS каюсь, не нашел где тут можно `.query(...)` вставить :D

Comment: Эээ, но mean это и есть sum/len, если я не торможу спросонья, так что без разницы. Но можно придумать варианты, когда mean бы не подошёл, конечно